# I want to say in Latin “remember the good times” how is this said in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

For context I do not know if it matters it’s from a male to another male. The nature of our friendship has changed.

Comment: is this "do you remember the good times?" or "I command you to remember the good times." can also be "I remember the good times" it matters. why? cause Latin is a mood language.

Answer (score -2):

"*Remember the good old times.*" would be "*Memento bonorum veterum temporum.*".

Latin for "*remember*" is the defective verb "*memini*", and its imperative is the irregular "*memento*", and its object goes in the genitive case.

Comment: Please don't translate idioms word-for-word. :(

Comment: @Cairnarvon How do you recognize when something is an idiom?